# How to generate one page per module with sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

We are using Sphinx to generate our Python documentation.

This is the command line we use:

```
sphinx-apidoc -F -o %WORKSPACE%\docs_rst %PACKAGE%

sphinx-build -b html %WORKSPACE%\docs_rst %WORKSPACE%\docs
```

The problem is that we get one page per package. What we would really need though is one page per module as the page gets way too long otherwise.

How would I set this up please?

Comment: No we didn't have the time to do something custom. Hope it will be included in a future update

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have submitted a patch to Sphinx to do exactly what you are asking for -- it adds a commandline option to apidoc that will put each module on its own page.

Patch can be viewed here: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/pull-request/161/added-option-to-apidoc-to-write-each

It's currently pending a merge into Sphinx, the command will add a separate tag that will work thusly:

`sphinx-apidoc -o [output_dir] [package_dir] --separate`

Comment: For everyone wondering: This command creates the .rst-files for the modules. Those will be used to create the documentation. So execute the sphinx-apidoc command, include all files and then run make.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this using the `autosummary` extension and the `sphinx-autogen` script (possibly using custom templates).